# how to make JDialog with checkboxes

Tags: java, checkbox, jdialog

I am writing a Java program and I ran into a problem. I have an `ArrayList<JCheckBox>` and I want to show some dialog window with these checkboxes, so I can choose some of them and I want another `ArrayList<>` of the selected objects as an outcome after closing that dialog. I think I can get results by adding `ActionListener` to those checkboxes, but I don´t know how to pass that `ArrayList<JCheckBox>` to the dialog window..

So far I tried something like this:

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> al = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for (MyClass mc : sr.getFields().values())
{
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(mc.getType());
    al.add(box);
}
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, al);
```

If I try to print the text in the checkbox, it is ok, but the dialog shows only a long line of some text that does not make any sense..

So, is there a way how to do that?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showConfirmDialog` method has to interpret the message object in order to render it correctly and it doesn't know how to interpret an `ArrayList`, you have to add all your elements to an `JPanel` eg:

```
JPanel al = new JPanel();
for (MyClass mc : sr.getFields().values()){
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(mc.getType());
    al.add(box);
}
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, al);
```

or an `Object[]` eg:

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> al = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for (MyClass mc : sr.getFields().values()){
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox(mc.getType());
    al.add(box);
}
Object[] obj = (Object[]) al.toArray(new Object[al.size()]);
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(ui, obj);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn´t thought of that.. BTW, is there a way how to display ArrayList of checkboxes in the dialog window? Is it even possible, or is it necessary to write my own JDialog class?